# What is the lifetime of cloud foundry user provided environment variables?

Tags: environment-variables, cloud-foundry

Cloud Foundry documentation clearly states that CF runtime ensures availability of the environment variables even when the application is stopped and restarted. I understand that user provided or application specific environment variables can be unset via the cf cli unset-env command. 
But are there any other situations where they can be unset or lost without explicitly being unset, e.g during a subsequent update of the application or redeployment or creation of a new container or droplet?
In other words, what is the validity of an environment variable that I set via set-env command, assuming I don't include it as part of the manifest yaml in any subsequent deployment of my application? Does CF runtime ensure it is available for my application forever until I explicitly unset it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's available forever until you explicitly unset it.

Comment: Is there any CF documentation explaining this?

Comment: Or until you delete the application.